# Php top list from arrays

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

How do you make someone who has a higher `subscriberCount` be sorted to the top? For example, I want to list the top 50 by `subscriberCount`. Currently it just sorts by the order added to `$topchan1["items"]`. I need to order by the highest `subscriberCount`.

```
$topchan1 = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?id='
    .$kanalas1.'&part=snippet%2Cstatistics&key='.$API.''),true);

$videoList = array_merge($topchan1["items"],$topchan2["items"],$topchan3["items"],$topchan4["items"]);

    foreach ($videoList as $key => $part) {
          $sort[$key] = sort($part['statistics']['subscriberCount']);
    }

    array_multisort($sort, SORT_DESC, $videoList);
    $i = 1;
    for( $i = 0 ; $i <= count($videoList)-1 ; $i++ )
    {   
        if(isset($videoList[$i]["statistics"]["subscriberCount"])) {
            echo $videoList[$i]["statistics"]["subscriberCount"].' _ ';
        }
    }
```

how looks

```
array ( 0 => array ( 'kind' => 'youtube#channel', 'etag' => '"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/Wj45BU6eiZOcR9nLVG4cXvflUNY"', 'id' => 'UCgQ1CeGtjCbkvslmG3zTAFA', 'snippet' => array ( 'title' => 'ILYA STREKAL', 'description' => 'Привет, меня зовут Илья Стрекаловский, добро пожаловать на мой канал!', 'customUrl' => 'BayanCover', 'publishedAt' => '2013-01-13T15:44:18.000Z', 'thumbnails' => array ( 'default' => array ( 'url' => 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AN66SAytpuX_75kGnsI5bvr_EkGTeQtZy3AJJXfH2w=s88-mo-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no', 'width' => 88, 'height' => 88, ), 'medium' => array ( 'url' => 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AN66SAytpuX_75kGnsI5bvr_EkGTeQtZy3AJJXfH2w=s240-mo-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no', 'width' => 240, 'height' => 240, ), 'high' => array ( 'url' => 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AN66SAytpuX_75kGnsI5bvr_EkGTeQtZy3AJJXfH2w=s800-mo-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no', 'width' => 800, 'height' => 800, ), ), 'localized' => array ( 'title' => 'ILYA STREKAL', 'description' => 'Привет, меня зовут Илья Стрекаловский, добро пожаловать на мой канал!', ), 'country' => 'RU', ), 'statistics' => array ( 'viewCount' => '234688406', 'commentCount' => '0', 'subscriberCount' => '2254032', 'hiddenSubscriberCount' => false, 'videoCount' => '153', ), ), 

1 => array ( 'kind' => 'youtube#channel', 'etag' => '"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/1vk-0WWcl2cpv1LO_4WQGsb2Qhk"', 'id' => 'UCMnOYmqiAQhE51l6AzEuOBA', 'snippet' => array ( 'title' => '', 'customUrl' => 'yanshelestx', 'publishedAt' => '2016-01-08T13:06:33.000Z', 'thumbnails' => array ( 'default' => array ( 'url' => 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AN66SAx6VddPszhqRGnHG48L5wVzTyf-h9lFa4F9Ig=s88-mo-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no', 'width' => 88, 'height' => 88, ), 'medium' => array ( 'url' => 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AN66SAx6VddPszhqRGnHG48L5wVzTyf-h9lFa4F9Ig=s240-mo-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no', 'width' => 240, 'height' => 240, ), 'high' => array ( 'url' => 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AN66SAx6VddPszhqRGnHG48L5wVzTyf-h9lFa4F9Ig=s800-mo-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no', 'width' => 800, 'height' => 800, ), ), 'defaultLanguage' => 'ru', 'localized' => array ( 'title' => 'Shelest', 'description' => 'Hello! This channel is dedicated to high-tech. I\'m a big lover of quality products for an adequate cost. The channel will express the personal opinion of the purchased goods and to listen to your words. Thank you!', ), 'country' => 'UA', ), 'statistics' => array ( 'viewCount' => '53038697', 'commentCount' => '0', 'subscriberCount' => '404844', 'hiddenSubscriberCount' => false, 'videoCount' => '123', ), ), 

2 => array ( 'kind' => 'youtube#channel', 'etag' => '"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/sSeA4B5B1NeVdRrLvhV6IQk9AJs"', 'id' => 'UCEFpNxeybzVwRbnYabQsXEg', 'snippet' => array ( 'title' => 'Bass Music Movement', 'description' => 'Music Promotion & Record Label Submissions/Business inquiries: bassmusicmovement@outlook.com', 'customUrl' => 'brazilianbassmovement', 'publishedAt' => '2017-03-06T02:48:38.000Z', 'thumbnails' => array ( 'default' => array ( 'url' => 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AN66SAx25V8TX9UzZkzfLlHPFH9yFjxQQQFeILTi=s88-mo-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no', 'width' => 88, 'height' => 88, ), 'medium' => array ( 'url' => 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AN66SAx25V8TX9UzZkzfLlHPFH9yFjxQQQFeILTi=s240-mo-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no', 'width' => 240, 'height' => 240, ), 'high' => array ( 'url' => 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AN66SAx25V8TX9UzZkzfLlHPFH9yFjxQQQFeILTi=s800-mo-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no', 'width' => 800, 'height' => 800, ), ), 'localized' => array ( 'title' => 'Bass Music Movement', 'description' => 'Music Promotion & Record Label Submissions/Business inquiries: bassmusicmovement@outlook.com', ), 'country' => 'BR', ), 'statistics' => array ( 'viewCount' => '136215709', 'commentCount' => '0', 'subscriberCount' => '748023', 'hiddenSubscriberCount' => false, 'videoCount' => '46', ), ),

3 => array ( 'kind' => 'youtube#channel', 'etag' => '"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/VwnSAHbLaj-RwQW8QKFECxplCp4"', 'id' => 'UCAf-RYRpQgxpj8voC29ck7w', 'snippet' => array ( 'title' => 'Hard Play', 'description' => '', 'customUrl' => 'hardplaygamechannel', 'publishedAt' => '2016-06-23T20:39:00.000Z', 'thumbnails' => array ( 'default' => array ( 'url' => '', 'width' => 88, 'height' => 88, ), 'medium' => array ( 'url' => 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AN66SAyu2XfSQsqjyNqu-fTTjleD9XzLSLoLsP-8Yw=s240-mo-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no', 'width' => 240, 'height' => 240, ), 'high' => array ( 'url' => 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a-/AN66SAyu2XfSQsqjyNqu-fTTjleD9XzLSLoLsP-8Yw=s800-mo-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no', 'width' => 800, 'height' => 800, ), ), 'localized' => array ( 'title' => 'Hard Play', 'description' => '', ), 'country' => 'RU', ), 'statistics' => array ( 'viewCount' => '39723260', 'commentCount' => '0', 'subscriberCount' => '784162', 'hiddenSubscriberCount' => false, 'videoCount' => '260', ), ), )
```

Comment: i need just sort who have bigger value he shows upper then others. like TOP LIST 1. 2. 3. places

Comment: well, why don't you sort in mysql? I assume data comes from db

Comment: i get all data from json api

Comment: _i get all data from json api_ So maybe there is a sorting flag in your api request which you could set

Comment: no :( only need do with php i already do another code with sort by publishDate, now need do that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value there you can see an accurate answer for sorting multi dimensional array

Comment: Use `usort()` method

Comment: Vivek not working or i do something bad

Comment: it's at seccond line videoList just merge jsons. i added full code now its working just need do sort

Comment: added how looks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `usort()` with custome function where you can compare `viewCount` and sort array in `DESC` order

```
function sortByviewCount($a, $b) {
    return ($a['statistics']['viewCount'] > $b['statistics']['viewCount']) ? -1:1;
}

usort($videoList, 'sortByviewCount');

print_r($videoList);
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/HqXVc

Comment: but i have about 60 channels json and i need all them sort your code sort only 2 arrays yes?

Comment: `$videoList` need to have mergerd data of all `60 channels json` and then my code will work for that also

Comment: tested it's work! thanks !!!